# I am calling two methods in ng-change. Is it good to use two methods. or is there any issue with it?

Tags: angularjs, html

Here I am using two methods in ng-change. Both methods are working properly. Just want to know is it safe to use.

```html
<input type="radio" name="payments" id="initiatePayments"
  ng-model ="initiatePayments" value="initiatePayments"
  ng-change="scope.checkStuff('initiatePayments'); "scope.checkDate();"> Initiate
```

Comment: usually they are fine..if the first method is not `async` method..

Comment: you can call a method that wraps the two.

Comment: Thanks for your response....Can u pls tell me what kinda issue we will face if it is async method ??

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma the second needs a stuff which will get it from the first method `async` response.

Comment: You have got an extra " in your ng-change directive.

Comment: @Chris Hermut...thanks :)